# How can I diminish my voxel terrain's height smoothly instead of randomly?

Tags: unity, c#, procedural-generation, voxels, perlin-noise

I have a script that is supposed to diminish height smoothly when an int is lowered, I tried perlin noise to make it lower like it would if it where terrain, which is the goal I'm after, but it only does removes entire layers.

```
public float heightIndex;
private height Height;

public void Start()
{
    Height = FindObjectOfType<height>();
    //the failed perlin test
    //heightIndex = transform.position.y + Mathf.PerlinNoise(heightIndex, heightIndex);
    heightIndex = transform.position.y + Random.Range(3, 10);
}
public void Update()
{
    if (Height.heightdetermine<heightIndex)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

[image: this is the problem, I need it to remove smoothly]

Thank you @DMGregory for fixing my dyslexic mess and bad grammar.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. Can you clarify? Is `heightIndex` the height you want to lower, or is it the value by which to lower some other value? Also, are you trying to lower a single value or several points? If several points, do you want them to lower by the same amount, or to be lowered more based on distance from some point?

Comment: sorry for being unclear. Im trying to lower and raise the terrain with a variable, which iv'e already created, but i want it have change shape smoothly,like with perlin noise, so when you lower  the heightIndex  you lower how high the terrain is, as well as change the shape.

Comment: I guess you are using a 3d noise? then use a vertical "ramp" to attenuate it? offsetting the vertical ramp and changing it's rate of change might do what you need. Else you can do the 2d perlin be the heitghfield and carve it with 3d noise. changing the amplitude, scale and generation height of the 2d perlin will help.